# Show a clock during execution of script

Tags: powershell, time

I am looping through a list of items and doing a write-progress on each item.

Is it possible to show a timer during the script execution?

For example show `$elapsedTime` with

```
$elapsedTime = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

as basis each second. But would this be possible in the same powershell window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
$elapsedTime = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

1..1000 | %{write-progress -activity "Working..." -status "$([string]::Format("Time Elapsed: {0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}", $elapsedTime.Elapsed.hours, $elapsedTime.Elapsed.minutes, $elapsedTime.Elapsed.seconds))" -percentcomplete ($_/10);}

$elapsedTime.stop()
```

Comment: Thabk you!! The only thing is that the timer only updates on each iteration of the loop, not every second..

Comment: After close consideration (!) I've decided that this will do! Works fine:) I just prefix with "updated on each loop". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something like this work:

```
1..100 | %{write-progress -activity "Search in Progress" -status "$_ Time: $($elapsedTime.Elapsed)" -percentcomplete $_;}
```